# Javascript object not returning value with variable key

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am attempting to retrieve a callback function set inside an object using a key stored in a variable. I am using node v6.3.1.

```
function ManageCommands() {
    var scope = this;
    scope.commands = {};

    return {
        addCommand: function (command, callback) {
            scope.commands[command] = callback;
        },
        compileCommands: function () {
            return Object.keys(scope.commands);
        },
        runCommand: function (key) {
            console.log('command', key);
            console.log('commands', scope.commands);
            console.log(scope.commands[key]);
        }
    };
}
```

However when attempting to access the callback function inside runCommand it returns undefined.:

```
$ node server.js
command test me
commands { hello: [Function], 'test me': [Function] }
undefined

$ node server.js
command hello
commands { hello: [Function], 'test me': [Function] }
undefined
```

I feel like I'm missing something really simple, the command is returned in type string.

I expect `console.log(scope.commands[key]);` to return [function] but that isn't happening.

Any insights?

Comment: We need to see more code. How is server.js calling your ManageCommands object? Can you give us a jsbin or jsfiddle that reproduces the problem?

Comment: In `runCommand`, please do: `console.log('command', JSON.stringify(key))`, and report back what you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Console.log does not print special characters for return and new line.

I pushed the string into an array for which I output:

```
[ 'hello\r' ]
```

I stripped the return and my function is working as expected.